# Unit testing side outputs

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm unit testing a ParDo function with Apache Beam that has 1 main output and 1 sideoutput:

```
public class GetPubsubMessageDoFn extends DoFn<PubsubMessage, PubsubPayload.PubsubPayloadDTO> {

  @ProcessElement
  public void processContext(ProcessContext processContext) {
    PubsubPayload pubsubPayload = new PubsubPayload(processContext.element());
    processContext.output(pubsubPayload.getPayload()); //main output
    processContext.output(ORIGIN_PATH_TUPLE_TAG, GCSUtils.toGSURL(pubsubPayload.getPayload().bucket, pubsubPayload.getPayload().name)); //side output
  }
}
```

I set up a unit test class for testing the main - and side outputs:

```
 public class GetPubsubMessageDoFnTest {

      private DoFnTester<PubsubMessage, PubsubPayloadDTO> getPubsubMessageDoFn;   
      private Injector injector;
      private final TupleTagList tags = TupleTagList.of(PUBSUB_PAYLOAD_DTO_TUPLE_TAG).and(ORIGIN_PATH_TUPLE_TAG);


      @Before   
      public void setup() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new GetPubsubMessageTestModule());
        this.getPubsubMessageDoFn = DoFnTester.of(injector.getInstance(GetPubsubMessageDoFn.class));
        this.getPubsubMessageDoFn.setOutputTags(tags); //Does not compile
      }

  //Tests
```

According to [the documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/#additional-outputs) I should be able to set the side output using  `setOutputTags(tags)` only that function does not exist on the `DoFnTester` class. I'm using the [Google Cloud Dataflow dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all/2.1.0) version 2.1.0, which does use a subset of Apache Beam's features, but even looking at the Apache Beam reference documentation for [DoFnTester](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/) `setOutputTags` isn't listed (even though it's mentioned again in the intro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These methods are not available in 2.1.0. In fact, DoFnTester is being deprecated, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3159.

The advice is to use TestPipeline with the DirectRunner to test a ParDo on their DoFn. You can carefully control the flow of input with TestStream. See a nice [blog](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2016/10/20/test-stream.html) on this topic.